# Font won’t change color

Tags: html, css

Newer to using HTML for a blog and I’m trying to set a title font to a certain color. All the other aspects I put in are working, just not the color. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

```css
h1 {
  color: #a7cf4c;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 35px;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<font>
  <h1>Title Test</h1>
</font>
```

Comment: Use ` h1{color: '#a7cf4c';}`

Comment: Don't use the `<font>` tag. Also, I just pasted your code into a snippet in your question and the color appears to work

Comment: @Nitheesh isn't that what was used?

Answer (score 0):

First of all..

1. You don't have to repeat `h1` each time when specifying a style.
2. Don't use `<font>` tag

Here's an example [Click here to see the example](https://jsfiddle.net/modgpuLc/5/)

```css
h1 {
  color: #a7cf4c;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<h1>Header Tag</h1>
```

Comment: @SauravPathak Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font

Answer (score 0):

### `<font>` deprecated in HTML 4.01

> Do not use **[`<font>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font)** element! Though once normalized in **HTML 3.2**, it was **deprecated in HTML 4.01**, at the same time as all elements related to styling only, then made obsolete in **HTML5**.
> Starting with **HTML 4**, HTML does not convey styling information anymore (outside the  element or the style attribute of each element). For any new web development, styling should be written using CSS only.

**Note:-** The former behavior of the **`<font>`** element can be achieved, and even better controlled using the **CSS Fonts CSS properties**.

### [CSS Fonts CSS properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Fonts)

> ***CSS Fonts** is a module of CSS that defines **font-related properties** and how font resources are loaded. It lets you define the style of a font, such as its `family`, `size` and `weight`, `line heigh`t, and the `glyph variants` to use when multiple are available for a single character.*

You can add color to `h1` color property in CSS.

```css
h1 {
  color: #a7cf4c;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<h1>Title Test</h1>
```

Comment: What did this answer add that hasn't been stated multiple times?